# Validación de sesion C#

Tags: c#, poo, login

Bueno una pregunta tonta vi este código en un vídeo para la verificar la sesión aplicando POO  y MySql desde xampp,pero no entiendo que es lo que hace esta clase y para que el motivo del arraytlist.

```
public ArrayList sesiones( Login objusuario)
{
  string comando = string.Format("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE Nombre='{0}'AND Contraseña='{1}';", objusuario.Usuario, objusuario.Contraseña);
  MySqlCommand adapter = new MySqlCommand(comando,conectar());
  MySqlDataReader lectura;
  ArrayList sesion = new ArrayList();
  lectura = adapter.ExecuteReader();
  while (lectura.Read())
  {
   sesion.Add(lectura["id_usuario"].ToString());
  }  
  Cerrarconexion();
  return sesion;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido!, te recomiendo que des una vuelta por el Tour de bienvenida y ademas de ver como funciona StackOverflow de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Es importante que leas ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?, así tu pregunta sera bien recibida.  ¿Podrías añadir el vídeo del que hablas en un enlace?

Comment: Yo por mi parte no veo la utilidad del ArrayList, se supone que esa consulta a SQL "deberia" devolverte un solo registro ya que no deberia haber id_usuarios repetidos con lo que un simple String te valdria. Otra cosa que veo , o en este caso no veo son control de excepciones algo vital en estos casos

Comment: Por un lado, si estas validando un inicio de sesión, no tiene mucho sentido retornar una lista, por otro, la clase ArrayList es totalmente obsoleta (aunque Microsoft aún no haya usado `[Obsolete]`), te recomiendo que busques otras fuentes un poco más confiables para aprender a hacer lo que andas buscando

Answer (score 1):

En el codigo que publicas el array esta conteniendo la lista de id asociada al usuario que se autentica, aunque es incorrecto la forma en que se implementa ya que se supone solo deba existir un unico id de usuario

```
public bool sesiones(Login objusuario)
{
  string comando = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE Nombre = ?nombre AND Contraseña = ?password";
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando,conectar());
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre",objusuario.Usuario);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", objusuario.Contraseña);

  int cant = adapter.ExecuteScalar();

  Cerrarconexion();

  return cant > 0;
}
```

como veras se usa siempre parametros y debes obtene rla cantidad de registros por eso el `COUNT` con el `ExecuteScalar()`